# Android ScrollView issue

Tags: android, scrollview

We are trying to make a board with sticky notes. We have used ScrollView in which we have LinearLayout. We have four columns. If there are more than 3 notes in one column, scrollview comes up. Issue is, if I try to move Row 5 column 1 note to Row 1 Column 2, scroll views hides all the notes. If we scroll to top of the board, notes become visible again. Any idea what's the issue ?

Thanks

Salman

Comment: Can we have some code? Thanks, Guys

Comment: maybe some screenshots would be helpful in this case, too